# Ambient Light Sensor Sony Vaio

Tags: sony, sensors

I want to install the ambient light sensor on my laptop but it is not possible that they are not drivers. As I can do because I am a novice in free software and this I like and do not want to another system with blue screen of death

My laptop is a Sony Vaio VPCF111FD
Nvidia GForce 330M
4 GB RAM
500 GB Hard Disk
16"